# Laravel - check value before validation and update request value cause DB default value is ignored

Tags: php, html, laravel

in my Laravelproject I have a form to update a given data.

When I insert the "amount" which should be inserted as default "1.00" - when there is no special entry --> null
but the DB is adding *null* instead of the default value *1.00*.

So what I thought was to check the input before validation and when it´s *null* I will replace it by the default value myself.

What I tried was(every time before the update with the validation happened):

1)

```
$name = $request->input('name'); 

if ($amount == null) {
    if ($this->$request->has('amount')) {
        $this->merge([
           'amount' => 1
        ]);
    }
}
```

2)

```
$this->request->merge([
  'amount' => 1,
]);
```

or

```
$this->request->merge([
  'amount' => '1',
]);
```

**Some Information about my Structure:**

This is my DB-Model:

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('amount',10,2)->default('1.00')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('userID')->nullable();
        $table->string('active', 20)->default('is active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my Item-Model:

```
protected $table = 'items';

protected $fillable = ['id','name','amount','image','description','userID','active','created_at','updated_at'];
```

This is my update:

```
Items::where('id', '=', $itemID)->first()->update($this->_validate($request));
```

This is my validation:

```
public function _validate(Request $request)
{
    $rules = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'amount' => '',
        'description' => ''
    ]);
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: The problem is that my DB default value is ignored (I think the backend is the problem) so I tryed to set the default myself with the variant 1) and 2) but none of them worked --> every time I get a _null_ in my DB instead of the default _1.00_ or _1_ --> what should I change / do, so that I get this default value instead of that _NULL_

Comment: Maybe you can make your database amount attribute not nullable. Or perhaps removing the amount (if empty) from the rquest works. Like `$request->remove('amount')`

Comment: 1) when I make it not nullable I get a 500 cause the value is null what the system wants to enter and 2) it´s like the same structure as i tried with the update --> but I think it doen´t change anything cause in my log I never get a value of the amount when the input field was empty (and I don´t want to have a default textvalue in the input)